# How can I add a button to dijit ToolBar at most right/left position?

Tags: toolbar, dojo

I have the following toolbar:

I would like to add "Logout" button on the most left postion.
How can I do that?

[image]

Toolbar URL:

```
http://77.235.53.170/split/split.htm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add style:'float:left;' or style:'float:right;'in data-dojo-props

```
 <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ToggleButton" id="toolbar1.layout" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'Pan', showLabel:true", style:'float:left;'>Layout</div>
```